# Change Prompt to Short Path

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, ms-dos

If I am in command prompt (Windows 7), and I am in a directory with a very long name (ex: C:\Users\Oorang\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\My Project\My Project\bin\Release), is there a way to quickly reduce the prompt to the short path without typing the whole thing in all over again (Ex: C:\Users\Oorang\DOCUME~1\VISUAL~1\Projects\DATAST~2\DATAST~1\bin\Release)?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. The only thing that I have seen reliably produce this is to run some sort of 16-bit program (which of course won’t work if you’re using 64-bit Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the `pushd` and `popd` commands.

Comment: That doesn’t work.